# 0.15 second per REST insert with elasticsearch

Tags: windows, rest, http, elasticsearch, request

I use elasticsearch with REST ( on Windows System , i use http request)
Every POST take 0.15 secondes ( doc could be 1 word or 350 words)
( 0.05 ) with ssd drive.
CPU never use more than 1% or 2%

Could i improve this time ?
Thanks for reading me.

Answer (score 0):

Use bulks inserts. There is a fixed overhead of making an HTTP request. If you read up on it, you'll notice that 150ms is pretty near the average reported overhead of making a TCP connection. You just need to insert more documents per request to speed this up. Look at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html if you are not familiar.